# Firestore cloud functions : cannot read property 'userId' of undefined

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, cloud

I am not able to send the welcome email from cloud functions. Whenever a new user is created in my firestore withing "Users" collection with the path Users/userId.Here is my function

```
        exports.welcomeEmail = functions.firestore.document('Users/{userId}')
.onCreate((snap, context)=>{
    const userId = context.params.userId;

    const db = admin.firestore()

    return db.collection('Users').doc(userId)

    .get()
    .then(doc => {

        const user = doc.data()

        const msg = {
            to: user.email,
            from: 'cybertronjc3@gmail.com',
            subject: 'Welcome to COFOZ',

            templateId: '1c455865-4529-4ae1-8e5a-9a5b8eaf0157',
            substitutionsWrappers: ['{{', '}}'],
            substitutions: {
                name: user.name
            }
        };

        return sgMail.send(msg)

    })
    .then(() => console.log('email sent!'))
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
})
```

This is the error that I am getting.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'userId' of undefined
    at exports.welcomeEmail.functions.firestore.document.onCreate.event (/user_code/index.js:19:32)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:112:27)
    at next (native)
    at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:28:71
    at __awaiter (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:24:12)
    at cloudFunction (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:82:36)
    at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:710:26
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to get the new user by looking by userid in documents. Just get the newly created document from snap.

```
exports.welcomeEmail = functions.firestore.document('Users/{userId}')
.onCreate((snap, context)=>{
  const user = snap.data();
  const msg = {
        to: user.email,
        from: 'cybertronjc3@gmail.com',
        subject: 'Welcome to COFOZ',
        templateId: '1c455865-4529-4ae1-8e5a-9a5b8eaf0157',
        substitutionsWrappers: ['{{', '}}'],
        substitutions: {
            name: user.name
        }
  return sgMail.send(msg)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using an old version of the Cloud Functions SDK. Can you check the version you are using in the `package.json` file, under the "dependencies" node?

With the syntax you are using in your code, you should have a version which is equal or above 1.0.0.

See this doc (Migration Guide) for more info:  https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff and check the version in your package.json file.

You will see that to update to the new SDK, you should do:

> `npm install firebase-functions@latest --save`
>
> `npm install firebase-admin@5.11.0 --save`